# primefaces popup dialog

Tags: primefaces

I have a problem very similar to the one posted by this user on primefaces issue tracker. http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?can=1&q=3282&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary&id=3282

He/she was answered that it is a user error. Can somebody point me to the error? I maybe making the same mistake.

Thanks

Kelly

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with primefaces, I can tell you that it does not play nicely with using multiple forms on a page; and that is likely a large factor in that user's errors.

Hope that helps.  Are you having a particular error with a certain primefaces component?

Comment: As for the 'not' according to this link http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/help/jsp-jsfel/jsf_expression_language_intro.html#syntax it seems to be correct. And the multiple forms, well, I have several of them and they work. Unless it is a problem with the popup dialog....

Comment: yeah, I edited my answer based on the not.  I've been using primefaces for a while now; and in our team at work, we've had numerous problems when using primefaces with multiple forms.  It seem to have particular issues with submitting a form from elsewhere (not on the same form) or attempting to perform validation on pages with multiple forms.  Just my 2c, ymmv.

Comment: In that user's example code, each instance of update=":teste_main" should be update="teste_main".

Comment: I made some tests, and followed your ideas about multiple forms, twisted it a little bit more, and I got that users example working... which I am posting below..

Comment: Well, I wasnt able to post it, but what I did was place a unique h:form, that encloses everything else, and on the button that submits the dialog content I added a oncomplete="dlg.hide()". It worked. So, thanks @Brian for trying to help out!